# XML tests solve

Tags: c#, xml

I can't connect my XML file and my C# in microsoft visual studio. How do I solve this?

Comment: Hi @IT_XD_Yeet, welcome to StackOverflow. Please write your question very clearly, complete, and any example of what you are trying to do so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here you find what need to be in your DA

```
public class LeegstaandXML
{
    public string Index { get; set; }
    public string Aard  { get; set; }
    public string  Adres { get; set; }

    public static int intElementsCount;
    private List<LeegstaandXML> _leegstaand;

    public List<LeegstaandXML> Lleegstaand
    {
        get
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("Lijst_leegstaande_bedrijfspanden.xml");
            XmlNodeList elementlist = doc.GetElementsByTagName("fme:Lijst_leegstaande_bedrijfspanden");
            intElementsCount = elementlist.Count;

            _leegstaand = new List<LeegstaandXML>();

            _leegstaand.Add(new LeegstaandXML()
            {
                Index = elementlist[Form1.counter]["fme:Dossier_ID"].InnerXml,
                Adres = elementlist[Form1.counter]["fme:Adres"].InnerXml,
                Aard = elementlist[Form1.counter]["fme:Aard_van_het_gebouw"].InnerXml,

            });

            return _leegstaand;
        }
        set
        {
            _leegstaand = value;
        }
    }
}
```

This is your connection in your form

```
private void btnVullen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Leegstaand p = new Leegstaand();

        do
        {
            counter++;
            LeegstaandXML leegstaand2 = new LeegstaandXML();

            foreach(LeegstaandXML lp in leegstaand2.Lleegstaand)
            {
                leegstaandDA NewItem = new leegstaandDA(lp.Index, lp.Adres, lp.Aard);
                NewItem.AddItem();
              //ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new string[] { lp.id.ToString(), lp.aard, lp.adres, lp.index.ToString() });
              //  item.Tag = lp;
              //lsvLeegstaand.Items.Add(item);

            }
        } while (counter < LeegstaandXML.intElementsCount -1);

        MessageBox.Show("implementatie is geslaagd");
        counter = 0;

        leegstaandDA.Getleegstaand();

        foreach (Leegstaand l in leegstaandDA.Getleegstaand())
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new string[] { l.index.ToString(), l.adres, l.aard});
            item.Tag = l;
            lsvLeegstaand.Items.Add(item);
        }
}
```